# Printing characters using Nested loops

Tags: c#

today while I was coding I ran into a problem I couldn't figure out.

So my task is to print a chosen amount of characters, the catch is I need to also specify how much characters are in one line.

For example:

I need to print 24 characters '*'

1. I select the character.
2. Select how many: 24.
3. Select how many character per each line: 7.

Result should look something like this:

```
*******
*******
*******
***
```

I have to strictly use nested loops!

Code example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char character;
        int charAmount;
        int charAmountInLine;
        Console.WriteLine("Select character");
        character = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Select total amount of characters");
        charAmount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Select amount of characters in each line");
        charAmountInLine = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("");

        for (int i = 0; i < charAmount; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < charAmountInLine; j++)
            {
                
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: At some point you will have to deal with actually printing out a character (or more). What .NET/C# functions do you think are available to you to print characters on the screen/in the console?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. You sample code looks fine, minus the actual printing functionality. Add that in, test it out and make any necessary adjustments.

Comment: I know Console.WriteLine() and Console.Write() functions. The point is I don't understand how should I write my nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this program, you need to identify:

1. Number of lines that print full characters in a line (`row`)
2. Print the remaining characters (`remainder`)

Concept:

1. Iterate each row (first loop).
2. Print character(s) in a line (nested loop in first loop).
3. Once print character(s) in a line is completed, print the new row and repeat Step 1 to Step 3 to print full characters in a line if any.
4. Print the remaining character in a line (second loop).

```cs
int row = amount / characterPerLine;
int remainder = amount % characterPerLine;

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < characterPerLine; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(character);
    }
            
    Console.WriteLine();
}
        
// Print remaining character
for (int i = 0; i < remainder; i++)
{
    Console.Write(character);
}
```

[Demo @ .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tlV7y2)

Comment: Thank you very much, the response time is insane!

Answer (score 0):

First of all count number of rows for outer loop

```
int numberOfRows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)charAmount / charAmountInLine);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
{
    charAmount -= charAmountInLine;
    charAmountInLine = charAmount> charAmountInLine? charAmountInLine: charAmount;
    for (int j = 0; j < charAmountInLine; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(character);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: Note that this will not deal correctly with the situation when the total amount of characters is smaller than the amount of characters in each line (i.e., where charAmount < charAmountInLine).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
int row = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)charAmount/(double)charAmountInLine);
int column = 0;
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++)
{
    temp = (i * charAmountInLine);
    column = temp < charAmount ? charAmountInLine : temp - charAmount;

    for(int j = 0; j < column; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(character);         
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Note that this will not deal correctly with the situation when the total amount of characters is smaller than the amount of characters in each line (i.e., where charAmount < charAmountInLine).

Comment: @Jaood_xD, what's your implication? integer division would yield a different result for `int row = charAmount / charAmountInLine` compared to the respective code line in the answer, unless charAmount == charAmountInLine.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I believe there exists better approach without such unnecessary type conversion that could scare newbies.

Comment: @Jaood_xD, i agree with your latest comment. No argument there. But your first comment suggests (maybe unintentionally due to the chosen wording) that the floating point division and rounding as done in the answer code would be equivalent to an integer division, which it is not. A suggestion i'd like to dispel.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace yeah, my bad. Now I see that it looks really different from what firstly come on my mind.